# saving image URL using django shell

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want to save the url of images in my database using django shell
here is  my model

```
class Album(models.Model):
    reference = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture = models.URLField()
    artists = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, related_name='albums', blank=True)
```

here is what i did in the shell

`album = Album.objects.create(title="Funambule", picture="/home/etali/Images/moi.png")`
the url is correctly save in the database but it's impossible to load it in the view
here is the view

```
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <a href="/">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ album.picture }}" alt="{{ album.title }}">
        </a>
        <h3><a href="/">{{ album.title }}</a></h3>
        {% for artist in album.artists.all %}
            <p>{{ artist.name }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

here is the error that appears when I inspect the code

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it's the image path the problem

Comment: did you inspect the django admin to see whether the image is there ?

Comment: I have not yet set django admin